# Boost dominator tree for graph with custom vertex properties

Tags: c++, boost, boost-graph

I'm trying to use [boost::lengauer_tarjan_dominator_tree](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/graph/doc/lengauer_tarjan_dominator.htm#fig:dominator-tree-example) with a graph with [custom vertex properties](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/graph/doc/using_adjacency_list.html#sec:adjacency-list-properties), but can't get even a simple example to compile:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/dominator_tree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_map/property_map.hpp> 

struct GraphNode
{
    explicit GraphNode(unsigned i) : index {i} {}
    unsigned index;
};

using Graph = boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::listS, 
                            boost::bidirectionalS, GraphNode, boost::no_property>;

using Vertex = boost::graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor;

int main()
{
    Graph g {};

    const auto u = boost::add_vertex(GraphNode {0}, g);
    const auto v = boost::add_vertex(GraphNode {1}, g);
    const auto x = boost::add_vertex(GraphNode {2}, g);
    const auto y = boost::add_vertex(GraphNode {3}, g);
    const auto z = boost::add_vertex(GraphNode {4}, g);

    boost::add_edge(u, v, g);
    boost::add_edge(u, x, g);
    boost::add_edge(v, y, g);
    boost::add_edge(x, y, g);
    boost::add_edge(y, z, g);

    const auto index_map = boost::get(&GraphNode::index, g);

    std::vector<Vertex> dom_tree_pred_vector(boost::num_vertices(g),
                                             boost::graph_traits<Graph>::null_vertex());

    auto dom_tree_pred_map = boost::make_iterator_property_map(std::begin(dom_tree_pred_vector),
                                index_map);

    boost::lengauer_tarjan_dominator_tree(g, u, dom_tree_pred_map);
}
```

Which I tried to adapt from the [example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/graph/test/dominator_tree_test.cpp) given in the docs.

Here is part of the error message:

```
/usr/local/include/boost/graph/detail/adjacency_list.hpp:2544:33: error: cannot form a reference to 'void'
        typedef const value_type& const_reference;
                                ^
/usr/local/include/boost/graph/dominator_tree.hpp:355:31: error: no matching function for call to 'get'
    const IndexMap indexMap = get(vertex_index, g);
```

I've also tried to pass in the index map explicitly using the second form of the method, without success. I've noticed this methods interface seems a little different from other graph methods, such as [depth_first_search](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/graph/doc/depth_first_search.html), where the `vertex_index_map` is a named parameter.

Is it possible to use this method with custom vertex properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem - as ever - is with using something other than `vecS` for the vertex container. You lose the builtin `vertex_index` property, making it mandatory to supply it to the API.

Sadly this algorithm doesn't support custom vertex index maps well. You tried - correctly - by using `index_map`, but internally the algorithm still looks for `vertex_index_t` tagged property.

The only two ways in which I can see this work is,

1. to do the DFS stage manually (as even the all-argument overload of `lengauer_tarjan*` fails to forward the correct index map into the DFS). Then you could call the `lengauer_tarjan_dominator_tree_without_dfs` implementation and have the result.
2. *Alternatively* you could tell the library about your graph's index map.

*(Lastly, you could accept fate and use `vecS` as the vertex container selector. I suspect this is explicitly not what you wanted.)*

### DEMO

Using the second approach, which may be the most elegant. Here are the specializations/overloads to add:

```
namespace boost {
    template <>
        struct property_map<Graph, vertex_index_t> {
            typedef typename property_map<Graph, size_t GraphNode::*>::type type;
            typedef typename property_map<Graph, size_t GraphNode::*>::const_type const_type;
        };

    static auto get(vertex_index_t, Graph& g)       { return get(&GraphNode::index, g); }
    static auto get(vertex_index_t, Graph const& g) { return get(&GraphNode::index, g); }
}
```

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a9d084c53e1e20dd)</kbd>**

```
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/dominator_tree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_map/property_map.hpp> 

struct GraphNode
{
    explicit GraphNode(size_t i) : index {i} {}
    size_t index;
};

using Graph = boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::listS, boost::bidirectionalS, GraphNode, boost::no_property>;

namespace boost {
    template <>
        struct property_map<Graph, vertex_index_t> {
            typedef typename property_map<Graph, size_t GraphNode::*>::type type;
            typedef typename property_map<Graph, size_t GraphNode::*>::const_type const_type;
        };

    static property_map<Graph, vertex_index_t>::type       get(vertex_index_t, Graph& g)       { return get(&GraphNode::index, g); }
    static property_map<Graph, vertex_index_t>::const_type get(vertex_index_t, Graph const& g) { return get(&GraphNode::index, g); }
}

using Vertex = boost::graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor;

int main()
{
    Graph g {};

    const auto u = boost::add_vertex(GraphNode {0}, g);
    const auto v = boost::add_vertex(GraphNode {1}, g);
    const auto x = boost::add_vertex(GraphNode {2}, g);
    const auto y = boost::add_vertex(GraphNode {3}, g);
    const auto z = boost::add_vertex(GraphNode {4}, g);

    boost::add_edge(u, v, g);
    boost::add_edge(u, x, g);
    boost::add_edge(v, y, g);
    boost::add_edge(x, y, g);
    boost::add_edge(y, z, g);

    std::vector<Vertex> dom_pred(num_vertices(g), boost::graph_traits<Graph>::null_vertex());

    auto index_map = boost::get(&GraphNode::index, g); // equivalent to vertex_index_t now
    auto dom_tree_pred_map (boost::make_iterator_property_map(std::begin(dom_pred), index_map));

    // Run main algorithm
    boost::lengauer_tarjan_dominator_tree(g, u, dom_tree_pred_map);

    std::cout << "Result: ";
    for (auto v : dom_pred) {
        if (v == boost::graph_traits<Graph>::null_vertex())
            std::cout << "(root) "; 
        else
            std::cout << g[v].index << " "; 
    }
}
```

Prints

```
Result: (root) 0 0 0 3
```

Comment: Added a live demo with the specializations I hinted at [Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a9d084c53e1e20dd)

Comment: Brilliant! I'll see if I can make a request to Boost to get this method 'modernised'.

Comment: What part of it needs modernizing? You mean to get named parameter support on the algo entry points?

Comment: Yes... seems to be the norm for all the other algorithms in BGL that I've used.